# What does $\times_i \Sigma_i$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, game-theory, set-theory

I cannot for the life of me figure this out. The context is from game theory (source: *Game Theory* by Fudenberg, Tirole):

> ... the space of mixed strategy profiles is denoted $\Sigma = \times_i \Sigma_i$ with element $\sigma$.

It also appears (I think) in

> A symmetric Nash equilibrium is a Nash equilibrium $\sigma \in \sum := \times_i\Delta(S_i)$"

Any thoughts? Can cross-products be indexed? So confused and at this point, quite stressed because it's late.

Pictures of sources for reference:

[image: Second example (actually more important)]

[image: First example]

Comment: Hi Sarah. Could you cite the source where you are quoting?

Comment: The first quote is from  Fudenberg D, Tirole J. Game Theory. Cambridge, MA: MIT Press; 1991, ETA: the second from a homework

Comment: It's generally used to denote cartesian product. But let me see your source to see what they are using it.

Comment: Are you asking for a picture of it?

Comment: Not trying to be rude, I'm genuinely unsure

Comment: Nothing to be rude here. If you want to add a picture, you can affix. I am just saying $\times_i$ is generally used for cartesian product.

Comment: Just uploaded some images, hope they help.

Comment: It is plausibly the cartesian product of $\Sigma_i.$

Comment: Ok thanks. Given the context (and a few deep breaths), I think it makes sense

Comment: Yes, Sarah. You can continue reading the text. Basically they are dealing with the product space.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I agree with @User1865345: $\times_i \Sigma_i$ is a short-hand notation for $\Sigma_1\times\Sigma_2\times\cdots$.

Comment: @User1865345 - yes, that's what it is.  (I've taken multiple graduate-level game theory classes and I remember this.)